# Draw cube in glsl shader

Tags: shaders, glsl, voxels

I am working on a voxel engine. Currently my cubes are rendered as vbos. I thought, it may be better to load only the cooridinates of voxels to the shader and make it draw a cube itself. Can someone tell me, if thats possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently working on a voxel engine as well. And I have found a few interesting conclusions:

1. Have 6 different vbo's one for each side (each vbo has contains the vertices of all the blocks which you want to render). A vbo has 4 vertices (connect them to form triangles with an index buffer) per block which contains color information and possibly also lightning information.
2. You can subdivide your world into different `chunks` and generate a vbo per chunk each time that a chunk is changed. Or you can generate your vbo per frame and just add everything which is visible to the camera.
3. Greedy mesh generation resulted (for me) into a 80% performance boost (I generate my vbo's each frame (for now)).

In [a question of mine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106168/greedy-mesh-generation-for-a-voxel-based-game/106172) is my code for generating the meshes, this might also help you understand how I render my voxels.
I´m not implying that my method is the best method, but this has worked for me (so far).

Here are a few of my sources (which I used to come to these conclusions):

- [How can I optimise a Minecraft-esque voxel world?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12938/how-can-i-optimise-a-minecraft-esque-voxel-world)
- http://bytebash.com/2012/03/opengl-volume-rendering/
- http://0fps.net/2012/07/07/meshing-minecraft-part-2/

PS: This is not really an answer to the question you asked, but a suggestion. It is what I think is a better alternative.